# Allow user to resize form/dataGridView using their borders

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, resize

I am making a program using forms and dataGridViews. I want to allow the user to resize the forms and dataGridViews the same a person would resize there web browser or other window on their pc. By clicking and dragging the border of the window. I am currently using a simple version of doing this. I have a tiny picture box in the corner of a panel containing a datGridView with dock set to full and added the code:

```
private void pictureBox11_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        resize = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox11_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        resize = false;
    }

    //Resize the Ben. List dataGrid(dataGridView4)
    private void pictureBox11_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (resize)
        {
            this.panel4.Height = pictureBox11.Top + e.Y;
            this.panel4.Width = pictureBox11.Left + e.X;
        }
    }
```

This allows the user to do what I want, but not how I'd like them to do it. This way is acceptable, but I would very much like to know if I can do it the other way. "Other way" of course referring to the ability to click and drag the borders to resize. I'm hoping to lean some new useful info here, that can help me out in the future. So any help?

Comment: What is wrong with the default way of resizing in winforms? If you have docked/anchored controls, why do you want to implement your own mechanism? Have you looked at the `SplitPanel` control?

Comment: I'm not sure why I added forms into that question. The forms do allow that function on its own. But the dataGridViews don't. So the question is about dataGridViews. I have never used the SplitPanel before.

Comment: Then i would suggest you try to dock the DataGridViews in one or more SplitPanels and see if that solves your problem, if i understood it...

Comment: Just tried the SplitPanel. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Pretty much I want to be able to resize a dataGridView by draging the border of it. Like I said, the way I have it now works. I would just like to know how to do it using the border of the control as opposed to using a picturebox in the corner.

Comment: SplitPanel absolutely will work if you set it up correctly.  Thanks Jobo for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the MouseMove event. Check e.location to see if the mouse is near an edge or corner, then display the appropriate cursor. If the mouse button is down, change the datagridview.size or .location to match the mouse movement. (You'll need to grab the beginning of the drag in the mousedown event.)

This is similar to the way you outlined, but you should make the move relative to the beginning of the drag so you don't have a "jump" of a few pixels when the button is depressed. And, of course, there are 8 sides / corners to deal with. Also, it's important for the user to have some feedback with cursor changes.

It's simpler to use built-in anchoring or docking, but there's nothing wrong with this method.